# How to move reusable functionalities to a generic class and invoke another activity from there?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I am new to Android development and I am facing an issue in invoking an activity from a generic class where I have a reusable function.

I have MainActivity where I need to check if the application has Network connectivity and then check if the user is already signed in.

If the user is signed in I need to open the Rate activity otherwise I will open the Login activity.

I thought I can keep the logic that checks the Network connectivity and shows the popup reusable and move it to a Global class as below

```
public class Global extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static boolean hasConnectivity = false;
    public static boolean userSignedIn = false;

    String TAG = "Debug Log - Helper";

    Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = this;
    }

    private void networkConnectionErrorDialog(final Context context, final Class targetClass){
        Log.d(TAG, "Show Alert Dialog");
        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle(R.string.connection_error_title)
                .setMessage(R.string.connection_error_message)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.warning)
                .setPositiveButton(
                        R.string.try_again,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Trying Again");
                                isNetworkAvailable(context, targetClass);
                            }
                        }).show();
    }

    protected void isNetworkAvailable(Context context, Class targetClass) {
        if(NetworkUtil.isConnected(context)){
            Log.d(TAG, "Has connectivity");
            if(targetClass != null){
                Log.d(TAG, targetClass.toString());
                Intent targetIntent = new Intent(context, targetClass);
                startActivity(targetIntent);
            }
            hasConnectivity = true;
            return;
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG, "Has no connectivity");
            hasConnectivity = false;
            networkConnectionErrorDialog(context, targetClass);
        }
    }
}
```

I pass in the targetClass as Login.class or Rate.class (based on user signed in state) from the MainActivity where isNetworkAvailable() is invoked.

I am getting the following error. Could someone help me fix the issue and help me understand if my approach needs improvement?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.solitontech.dayatsoliton/com.solitontech.dayatsoliton.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3581)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3621)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2862)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4488)
        at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4445)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4806)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4774)
        at com.solitontech.dayatsoliton.Global.isNetworkAvailable(Global.java:50)
        at com.solitontech.dayatsoliton.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:68)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1355)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7117)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3556)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your application is experiencing a null pointer exception in your activity's onResume method. If you had called startActivityForResult, make sure that the data in

```
@Override 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{..}
```

is non null before processing it.

As for your question about starting an activity from your helper class Global, you can define a function like this.

```
private static void goToActivity(Context context, Class<?> activityClass){
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, activityClass);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

You can call this method as below.

```
goToActivity(context,TargetActivity.class);
```

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

```
Intent targetIntent = new Intent(context, targetClass);
startActivity(targetIntent);
```

above code is wrong. You should pass your current activity and target activity here.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, TargetingActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

As a example :
If you want to start ActivtyB form ActivtyA

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityD.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

1st try to correct this error. then you can find some others.